# Error in library(tidyr) : there is no package called ‘tidyr’

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am getting `Error in library(tidyr) : there is no package called ‘tidyr’` error while installing the `tidyr` package.

I'm using `version.string R version 3.2.3` version.

Comment: Try to update your R version.  It is a very old one

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are trying to load it, not install it.  To install you first run `install.packages("tidyr")`, then run `library(tidyr)`.

Also, your R version is pretty old.  Not sure it will work that far back.  You might consider upgrading if possible.

Comment: I already install it, and while loading getting this error.

Comment: Did it install successfully?

Comment: Yes, it did install sucessfully.