# Error in library(tidyr) : there is no package called ‘tidyr’ and installed.packages("tidyr")

Tags: r, tidyr

Im using the 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) version, and it says that there isnt such a package.
I've tried using installed.packages("tidyr") but I still get this error:
Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

Comment: It's `install.packages`. `installed.packages` returns installed packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in library(tidyr) : there is no package called ‘tidyr’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079577/error-in-librarytidyr-there-is-no-package-called-tidyr)

Comment: sorry! my bad, I did use install.packages("tidyr") and I still get the error : Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

Comment: That's the output you'd see from `installed.packages`, not `install.packages`, Maybe try restarting your R if you've goofed something up in your current R session.

Answer (score 1):

use `install.packages("tidyr")` instead of `installed.packages("tidyr")`.